# How to clone system drive

Tags: ssd, clone

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on 860 EVO M.2 500GB SSD drive.
Single boot os.
On last system re-boot there was a message at the bottom of the post screen:

"WARNING! Your HDD/SDD might crash at any moment."

The system still started up and is running fine since.

In addition to the SSD drive, there is another 2TB HDD installed holding backups and non OS data, so my first question is what SSD or HD is the cause of the warning message ?

I'd like if possible to avoid going thru a fresh install, so what is the best approach (assuming the SSD is about to fail) to replace the SSD with similar or larger SSD and clone the system SSD into the new SSD (and then remove the old SSD)

If for example I boot into a live CD and use DD to create an image file of the SSD on an external drive, can I then replace the SSD and again boot into live CD and run DD again to restore the image ?  Would that work ?

Comment: First bit - to work out which drive - if you’re not confident looking through logs, open the disks Utility and see if there are obvious warnings on either disk. If not and you can easily open your computer, I’d try disconnecting the non-os disk and rebooting. If you still get errors you know where the likely problem is.

Comment: Second bit - cloning to new drive - obviously depends on which disk is failing; could you also edit your question to give some information on your setup (dual vs single boot, what’s on the 2 drives, whether your system will be able to hold a third drive internally for the cloning).